# In Acts 5:3, what does it mean for Satan to fill the heart of Ananias?

Tags: acts

> [Act 5:3 NLT] (3) Then Peter said, "Ananias, why have you let Satan fill your heart? You lied to the Holy Spirit, and you kept some of the money for yourself.
>
> > [Act 5:3 MGNT] (3) εἶπεν δὲ ὁ Πέτρος Ἁνανία διὰ τί ἐπλήρωσεν ὁ Σατανᾶς τὴν καρδίαν σου ψεύσασθαί σε τὸ πνεῦμα τὸ ἅγιον καὶ νοσφίσασθαι ἀπὸ τῆς τιμῆς τοῦ χωρίου

Also, does Peter's bringing in a reference to "the breath that is holy" (τὸ πνεῦμα τὸ ἅγιον) to contrast it in some way with the heart being filled with the adversary (ὁ Σατανᾶς)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Acts 5:3, what does it mean for Satan to fill the heart of Ananias?**

> [Act 5:3 NLT] (3) Then Peter said, "Ananias, why have you let Satan
>   fill your heart? You lied to the Holy Spirit, and you kept some of the
>   money for yourself.

Filled your heart." In this context, the Greek expression conveys the meaning “to dare to do something; to embolden."

Then Peter said, "Ananias, why have you let Satan fill **[EMBOLDENED]** your heart? You lied to the Holy Spirit, and you kept some of the money for yourself.

For example in Esther 7:5  we have similar expressions, the NKJV writes: who would dare presume in his heart to do such a thing?” whilst the NIV renders it: "who has dared to do such a thing?”

Esther 7:5  (NKJV)

> 5 So King Ahasuerus answered and said to Queen Esther, “Who is he, and
>   where is he, **who would dare presume in his heart to do such a thing?”**

Esther 7:5  (NIV)

> 5 King Xerxes asked Queen Esther, “Who is he? Where is he—the man **who
>   has dared to do such a thing?”**

Esther 7:5 LXX Online

> 5 εἶπε δὲ ὁ βασιλεύς· τίς οὗτος, ὅστις **ἐτόλμησε** ποιῆσαι τὸ πρᾶγμα
>   τοῦτο;

H Αγία Γραφή στη Δημοτική (Filos Pergamos) (FPB)

Ελληνικά [Modern Greek] Esther 7:5

> 5 Tότε, ο βασιλιάς Aσσουήρης αποκρίθηκε και είπε στη βασίλισσα Eσθήρ:
>   Ποιος είναι αυτός, και πού είναι εκείνος, που **τόλμησε** να κάνει τέτοια
>   πράγματα;

Ecclesiastes 8:11 (NIV)

> 11 When the sentence for a crime is not quickly carried out, people’s
>   hearts are filled with schemes to do wrong.

Ecclesiastes 8:11  (NKJV)

> 11 Because the sentence against an evil work is not executed speedily,
>   therefore the heart of the sons of men is fully set in them to do
>   evil.

Ecclesiastes 8:11 LXX Online

> 11 ὅτι οὐκ ἔστι γινομένη ἀντίρρησις ἀπὸ τῶν ποιούντων τὸ πονηρὸν ταχύ·
>   διὰ τοῦτο **ἐπληροφορήθη καρδία υἱῶν** τοῦ ἀνθρώπου ἐν αὐτοῖς τοῦ ποιῆσαι
>   τὸ πονηρόν.

H Αγία Γραφή στη Δημοτική (Filos Pergamos) (FPB)

Ελληνικά [Modern Greek] Ecclesiastes 8:11

> 11 Eπειδή, η απόφαση ενάντια στo πoνηρό έργo δεν εκτελείται γρήγoρα,
>   γι’ αυτό η καρδιά των γιων των ανθρώπων είναι oλόκληρη έκδoτη στo να
>   πράττει τo κακό.

Comment: Please provide the underlying Greek text for the Esther and Ecclesiastes verses.Thanks.

Comment: Ruminator: done.

Comment: Ah! Ecclesiastes 8:11 is the ticket! Thank you! You should bold ἐπληροφορήθη καρδία υἱῶν. +1 and accepted as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like "Satan filled your heart" in verse 3 equals "you have contrived this thing in your heart" in 4. Have you ever contrived?

"Deceive the Holy Spirit" in 3 equals "lied...to God" in 4. Have you ever deceived? Or lied? If you have, then you may know the answer to your question